# Как дублированым строкам в mysql сделать update?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица в mysql с полями id, email, user, date, token, duplicate (где duplicate = 0), как сделать так чтобы при insert проверяло есть ли дубли и если они есть то вставлять но с параметром duplicate = 1.

Например:

в таблице есть строчки, у всех duplicate = 0 так как email везде разный, нужно сделать так, когда идет в базу insert и если email из insert совпадает уже c любым email из БД то вставлять этот email только с duplicate = 1.

Сейчас идет так, принимаем через ajax файл txt, потом перемещаем его в папку tmp, потом его разбиваем по строкам на строки в таблицу циклом while, и вставляем по строчке.

Вот кусок кода, где все это реализовано.

```
if ( $_FILES['file_base']["size"] < 52428800   ) {
if ( $_FILES['file_base']["error"] > 0 ) {
  echo "Ошибка: " . $_FILES['file_base']["error"] . "<br/><br/>";
} else {
  if ( file_exists( "" . $_FILES['file_base']["name"] ) ) {
    echo $_FILES['file_base']["name"] . "<b>- уже есть аткой файл</b>";
  } else {
    $sourcePath = $_FILES['file_base']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = "../tmp/" . $token . '.txt';
    move_uploaded_file( $sourcePath, $targetPath );
    $lines = file($targetPath);
    $lines = array_unique($lines);
    file_put_contents($targetPath, implode($lines));
    $fp = fopen($targetPath, 'rt');
    ini_set("memory_limit", "64M");
    if ($fp) {
      while (!feof($fp)) {
        $email = fgets($fp, 999);
        $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO `base_all` (email,user,date,token) VALUES('$email','$client_name','$date','$token')");
      }
    }
    else {
      echo "Ошибка при открытии файла";
    }
    fclose($fp);
    unlink($targetPath);
  }
}
}
```

p.s. Хочу отметить что insert происходит в БД не один раз, а много с txt файла, то есть в txt файле может быть до нескольких тысяч строк с email, сейчас сделано так: каждая строчка в файле это каждая строчка в базе, все вставляет все работает. Но оно вставляет еще и дубли, нужно дубли как-то апдейтить.

Comment: Если вставляется вторая запись с тем же email то надо вставить ее и именно в ней поставить duplicate=1 или же вставлять запись не надо, а duplicate=1 сделать у той, что уже есть в БД. если второе то сморите в сторону `on duplicate key update` (прямо по этой фразе тут поищите, найдете много готовых ответов)

Comment: Ну а если первое - то триггером. А если таблица MyISAM, и устраивает любое ненулевое duplicate, а не строго 1, то CREATE UNIQUE INDEX (email, duplicate), а само поле сделать автоинкрементом.

Comment: 1 вариант, нужно вставить еще раз такое но уже с duplicate = 1, это мне для того чтобы потом эти дубли показать. Можно поподробнее  ?

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем пришел к такому выводу: поставит index в БД на поле email и все.